# Android shifts all views to the other side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have an app with a login page.

[image: login layout]

As you can see, the textViews and editTexts are shifted to the left, but when i run this in a device that has hebrew as its language all these views are shifted to the right. This is probably because Hebrew is written from right to left. My question is how do i stop this from happening?

Comment: why do i always get downvoted i dont get it

Comment: Your question is too broad because you don't share your code. start by adding your layout code to the question. and one more thing, you may want to check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ItayS Don't worry. I too used to get it when I was beginner in programming and on StackOverflow. Read link shared by Tamir

Comment: can you please share your layout xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the android:supportsRtl="false" to the  element in your application manifest file.

[you can see more details of RTL tag](https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2)

Answer (score 4):

It is related to the RTL (rigth-to-left) native support.

In your **Manifest** you can configure globally for your app:

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

In the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#supportsrtl):

> Declares whether your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts.
>   If set to `true` and t`argetSdkVersion` is set to 17 or higher, various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts. **If set to `false` or if `targetSdkVersion` is set to 16 or lower, the RTL APIs will be ignored or will have no effect and your app will behave the same regardless of the layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice** (your layouts will always be left-to-right).
>
> The default value of this attribute is `false`.

Also you can configure for each view (and also layout) the **`android:layoutDirection`** attribute,

From [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection):

> Defines the direction of layout drawing. This typically is associated with writing direction of the language script used. The possible values are `ltr` for Left-to-Right, `rtl` for Right-to-Left, `locale`, and `inherit` from parent view. If there is nothing to inherit, "locale" is used. "locale" falls back to "en-US". `ltr` is the direction used in "en-US". **The default for this attribute is `inherit`.**

and the [`android:textDirection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textDirection) attribute which defines the direction of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the root view in your layout:

```xml
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

This forces the layout direction to be left-to-right, instead of being based on the locale.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without your code but I think that all you need to do is to add `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` to your layout.

This will tell your layout to be ltr and not change based on the device language